# how to read a value and pass it as parameter to next step in watir

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, watir

I am new to watir, and Need to know how to capture a value displayed on browser and pass the same as parameter to next step. here is how the html looks like.

Text -   xxxx yyyy zzzz aaaa

The text displayed is a card number. I need to capture the card number dipslayed and pass it as parameter to next step in my test

Comment: I don't know anything about what you're working on, but my first inclination is that this doesn't sound like a safe way to handle credit card numbers at all!

Comment: Great Point @adamreed I hope the site is using HTTPS for those pages.  I'd also encourage them to never display the full card number back to the user and limit it to something like the last 4 digits.  I would also check that they are doing something like getting a `BRIC` for the card and storing that rather than the card itself.  That makes things far safer for your customers if someone with ill intent ever gets access to a db, backups, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this cardnumber is contained in an HTML element like a div/span/table cell, then use that to locate the bit of text you need.

For example if your HTML was like this:

```
<div class="CC_Number">1234 5678 9012 3456</div>
```

Then you could use code like this:

```
cardnumber = browser.div(:class => "CC_Number").text
other_function(cardnumber)
```

You can also use regular expressions or other string manipulation to separate the number from other text on the page.

"Your credit card number is: 1234 5678 9012 3456."

```
cardnumber = browser.text              #get all browser text
     #"Your credit card number is: 1234 5678 9012 3456."
cardnumber = cardnumber.split(":")     #split the text at every colon
     #[0] = "Your credit card number is"
     #[1] = "1234 5678 9012 3456."
cardnumber[1].gsub(".", "")            #replace all instances of "." with ""
     #cardnumber = "1234 5678 9012 3456"
```

for an example of a regular expression to find the card number, see @Dave McNulla's answer below.

Answer (score 4):

```
cardnumber = browser.text.scan /\d{4} \d{4} \d{4} \d{4}/
other_function(cardnumber)
```

Comment: I've never had an opportunity to need "scan", but I'm glad to know it now for the future.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh yeah, it's a number so make that /\d{4} \d{4} \d{4} \d{4}/

Comment: yeah that would be the way if it is buried inside a bunch of other text and not wrapped by a div, table-cell or some other handy container element.  good use of regex.